# Не могу подключиться к серверу node.js через 192.168.x.x

Tags: node.js

При помощи **Advanced IP Scanner** я узнал, что мой локальный IP - *192.168.0.102*

Я запустил сервер **Node.js** и могу спокойно подключиться к нему через *localhost*, но когда я пробую подключиться по адресу *http://192.168.0.102* (обратите внимание на *http*), то в консоли браузера я получаю такие ошибки:

```
GET https://192.168.0.102/static/style.css                                         192.168.0.102/:8
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

```
GET https://192.168.0.102/socket.io/socket.io.js                                   192.168.0.102/:7
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

И т.д.

То есть я подключаюсь к *http://192.168.0.102*, а **Google Chrome** пытается получить файлы с *https://192.168.0.102*. При подключении к *192.168.0.102* загружается только файл `index.html`

Вот мой код:

```js
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
var path = require("path");
var sio = require("socket.io");
var helmet = require("helmet");

var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var io = sio(server);

const PORT = 80;

app.set("port", PORT);
app.use(helmet())
app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/static"));
app.use("/image", express.static(__dirname + "/image"));
app.use('/favicon.ico', express.static(__dirname + '/favicon.ico'));

function page_main(req, resp) {
    resp.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
}

function on_run() {
    console.log("Сервер запущен на порту " + PORT);
}

app.get("/", page_main);

server.listen(PORT, on_run);
```

Если я подключаюсь к *http://localhost*, то никаких ошибок в консоли **Google Chrome** нет и все файлы загружаются

```
C:\XAMPP\htdocs\sqcr>npm version
{
  sqcr: '1.0.0',
  npm: '7.19.1',
  node: '16.2.0',
  v8: '9.0.257.25-node.16',
  uv: '1.41.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.17.1',
  modules: '93',
  nghttp2: '1.42.0',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '6.0.1',
  openssl: '1.1.1k+quic',
  cldr: '39.0',
  icu: '69.1',
  tz: '2021a',
  unicode: '13.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.1.0-DEV',
  nghttp3: '0.1.0-DEV'
}
```

Comment: Задайте параметр [host](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen) `server.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', on_run);`

Comment: У меня не получается подключиться не при `server.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', on_run);`, не при `server.listen(PORT, '192.168.0.102', on_run);`

Comment: Смотрите настройки брандмауэра.

Comment: Я посмотрел, всё нормально. Кстати забыл написать, что при подключении к `192.168.0.102` файл `index.html` загружается, а вот все остальные нет

Comment: Я уже пробовал, не помогло

Comment: `__dirname` это в пути к файлу на компьютере, то есть например файл в браузере `/favicon.ico` станет доступен как файл на компьютере `__dirname + "/favicon.ico"`. И если бы проблема была в этом, то в `localhost` тоже файлы бы не загружались

Comment: А порт не пробовали менять? например 8080.

Comment: 192.168.0.102/:8 GET https://192.168.0.102:8080/static/style.css net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил эту проблему

Я перепробовал всё, но в конце концов я решил сгенерировать `SSL` сертификат

Также я сделал перенаправление с `HTTP` на `HTTPS`. Вот мой код:

```js
var express = require("express");
var https = require("https");
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var sio = require("socket.io");
var helmet = require("helmet");

const PORT = 443;
const HTTP_PORT = 80;

function page_main(req, resp) {
    resp.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
}
function http_page(req, resp) {
    resp.sendFile(__dirname + "/http/index.html");
}
function on_run() {
    console.log("HTTPS Сервер запущен на порту " + PORT);
}
function http_run() {
    console.log("HTTP Сервер запущен на порту " + HTTP_PORT);
}

var app2 = require("express")();
var httpServer = require("http").Server(app2);
app2.get("/", http_page);
httpServer.listen(HTTP_PORT, http_run);

var app = express();
var ssl = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.pem")
}
var server = https.createServer(ssl, app);
var io = sio(server);

app.set("port", PORT);
app.use(helmet());
app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/static"));
app.use("/image", express.static(__dirname + "/image"));
app.use('/favicon.ico', express.static(__dirname + '/favicon.ico'));

app.get("/", page_main);

server.listen(PORT, on_run);
```

Файл `./http/index.html`:

```html
<script>location.protocol="https"</script>
```

Я сгенерировал `SSL` сертификат при помощи *[minica](https://github.com/jsha/minica)* (`minica --domains localhost`) и теперь *192.168.0.102* работает